# Conversion from string '31/08/2012' to date is not valid?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have bound date in my web page from my sql server database.i.e.

```
Convert(CHAR(10), date, 103).
```

31/08/2012. Not 31/08/2012 12:00:00. When I insert this date into sql Server, I got the error like Conversion from string '31/08/2012' to date is not valid? I am using en-US format... And also I put datetimeformat as 'dd/MM/yyyy'. First I was using en-GB format. Same error comes. After that I changed en-GB to en-US format. Still that error comes. How to rectify that error?

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you...

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert date based on your culture in code behind file.

// Format in which u have enter your date

```
      string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

// Give your culture here

```
       CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

// txtDate.Text is your date field

```
       DateTime concatenatedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, format, c);
```

Now pass this concatenatedDate in query or store procedure through cs file.
It will surely works for you.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

convert date string to datetime like this

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

than pass to database resolve the issue

More details : [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dateReturn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert date in `"yyyy/MM/dd"` format. It will work.